# How do I hide a React component on the second click when the component is already open?

Tags: reactjs, components

On the first click of IconButton, the React component is shown and on the second click, I'd like to hide the component.

```
export default function EditorToolbar(props) {

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
}


 <IconButton size='small' onClick={handleOpen} >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default function EditorToolbar(props) {

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
}

return(
 <IconButton size='small' onClick={handleOpen} >
{open?show your react component here:null}
)
```